# Are there any dictionaries for Chrome that have more words out of the box?

Tags: google-chrome

For example, *setup*, *parallelize*, etc. are not present in the Chrome dictionary out of the box.

I am looking for a Chrome dictionary that is more comprehensive than its built-in one.